# pandas.Series.value_counts result to a dictionary with frequencies as keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list containing over 60k records and I'm trying to convert the `pandas.Series.value_counts()` result into a dictionary where the resultant frequency is the key and the all the records with the same frequency as values.

Example:

```
a    15
b    15
c    15
d    14
e    13
f    13
g    11
h    11
```

```
{
15: ['a', 'b', 'c']
14: ['d']
13: ['e', 'f']
11: ['g', 'h']
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [grouby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate using [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
import pandas as pd

# setup
s = pd.Series(list('a'*15 + 'b'*15 + 'c'*15 + 'd'*14 + 'e'*13 + 'f'*13 + 'g'*11 + 'h'*11))
s = s.value_counts()

# convert to a dataframe
df = s.to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={0 : 'counts'})

# groupby counts and aggregate using list
result = df.groupby('counts')['index'].aggregate(list).to_dict()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{11: ['h', 'g'], 13: ['e', 'f'], 14: ['d'], 15: ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

**Update**

Is also possible to do:

```
# convert to a dataframe
df = s.to_frame('counts').reset_index()
```

As suggested by @anky.

Comment: This works as wanted, I was just making the edit to add the `['index']` but you saw that as well. Thank you!

Comment: @anky Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and `agg` with the `list` constructor, and obtaining a dictionary from the series with [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
(s.reset_index().set_index('series_name')
   .squeeze()
   .groupby(level=0)
   .agg(list)
   .to_dict())
# {11: ['g', 'h'], 13: ['e', 'f'], 14: ['d'], 15: ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following **code** will help you

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('your path .csv')
df.groupby(['label','num']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```